# How to know which instance type available for HVM or PV?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2

We have script for automate EC2 instance creation using spot requests but we are facing a problem selecting the Instance Type because sometimes we get an AMI that has HVM and sometimes we get a PV AMI.

How can we identify which Instance Type we can use for HVM and which Instance Type we can take for PV?

Answer (score 0):

All current generation instance types [support HVM AMIs](https://aws.amazon.com/amazon-linux-ami/instance-type-matrix/). If you stumble upon a PV AMI, then you will have to choose between the M3 or C3 instance types.

Comment: Not the entire story.  The c1, m1, m2, and t1 instance classes also support PV AMIs.  The hi1 and hs1 support both PV and HVM. [Source.](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/UserGuide/virtualization_types.html)

Answer (score 0):

The [Linux AMI Virtualization Types](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/UserGuide/virtualization_types.html) documentation page (as of March 2017) says:

> All current generation instance types support HVM AMIs. The CC2, CR1, HI1, and HS1 previous generation instance types support HVM AMIs.
>
> ...
>
> The C3 and M3 current generation instance types support PV AMIs. The C1, HI1, HS1, M1, M2, and T1 previous generation instance types support PV AMIs.